# Recyclerview - Best practices to update a view in viewholder without modifying all of its views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have list of **feeds** to which a user can like/dislike, play video and see description of that feed. I implemented like feature in a way that when like is pressed, there is an api call and on success response I modify that Feed object and call **notifyItemChanged()**. But the issue here is, **onBindViewHolder()** is called again, which re-initializes the video. How am I supposed to tackle this issue without using any additional state variable in **Feeds** Object. I have to update like/dislike view, likes count, people who reacted and comments count but don't want to re-initialize the video and a few other views too.

[image]

Comment: have you tried notifyItemChanged(position) ?

Comment: You can use [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil).

Comment: notifyItemChanged(position) will still call onBindViewHolder() and cause all the views to re-initialize

Comment: I am using DiffUtils, but ofcourse if the item is changed it will bind the views again to the updated model.

Comment: Use Difftil with payload . `onBindViewHolder` has variant with payload you can use this to update the data .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, notify always rebinds your holder. To update something specific without full recreating, you shouls use Payloads - https://medium.com/livefront/recyclerview-trick-selectively-bind-viewholders-with-payloads-4b28e3d2cce8

Comment: payload with diffUtils: https://blog.undabot.com/recyclerview-time-to-animate-with-payloads-and-diffutil-4278beb8d4dd